# Georeferencing old British army map of Palestine?

Tags: georeferencing, israel, palestine

[image][image]

I'm using the georeferencer to try and reference a British army map of Palestine. I want it to later be added on Google earth.

I'm pretty sure it should be Palestine grid 1923 the map ends up appearing distorted in all sorts of places around the Middle East but not in Palestine.

What projection information do I need to input in the georeferencer? 
I'm currently entering palestine grid when inputing the map into the georeferencer. I'm adding the points according to the info on the legend on the right side of the map. exporting to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator

Comment: Can you add more details? Show some screen shots of the map and/or anything else relevant.

Comment: What georeferencer (i.e. what GIS software) are you using to try and do this?

Comment: Map face notes definitely tell you it is 'PALESTINE GRID'

Comment: Out of interest is this a homework question, there appears to be a very similar one posted at the same as yours!

Comment: hey, thanks for the replies. thankfully it's not a homework question.

Comment: I'm using QGIS and need to reference to WGS82 because after referencing I will be combining it with other materials already using that coordinate system. I'll attach a screenshot to in a moment to show how wrong its coming up on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326) and use the lat/lon values provided for the corners and along the outer grid.

Comment: Is it wise to use the WGS84 ellipsoid for those lat/longs, when the [Palestine Grid](https://epsg.io/28191) uses [Clarke 1880 (Benoit)](https://epsg.io/7010-ellipsoid)?

Comment: for georeferencing it is probably close enough